# Is it safe to compare dates using YYYY-MM-DD format instead of unix timestamp?

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I usually use `strtotime` first to convert YYYY-MM-DD to unix timestamp then compare them but this appears to work just fine:

`echo ('2015-01-01' < '2015-01-02')? 1 : 0;`
`// returns 1`

I was wondering, is this "simpler" method reliable for basic comparison operators e.g., `<`, `>`, `<=`, `=>`?

Comment: Works but I wouldn't do it like that. What if the date-format is different or invalid? Check this: http://en.code-bude.net/2013/12/17/how-to-compare-dates-in-php/ I would use the last example there.

Comment: But what if date format changes.Result will become zero.This is safe until date has same format on both side.For accurate result to use **strtotime **

Answer (score 3):

Comparing strings in PHP using `<` and `>` is not a good idea because implicit type conversions to integers and other types are involved.

Using [strcmp](https://php.net/strcmp) is better and will actually work, dates in YYYY-mm-dd have the same ordering chronologically and alphabetically. It is often used in databases where an index is created on a datetime column and then using WHEREs the column is filtered by comparing strings.

I will strongly recommend though creating `\DateTime` or `\DateTimeImmutable` objects and working with those (you can use comparison operators on them). UNIX timestamps were a good choice before PHP 5.2, but today the object approach is the better one.

Comment: absolutely right, the datetime objects are the way to go